# ACT ids are getting indexed by search engines. How can I prevent that?

Tags: action

I am using a module (AdMan) that generates an ACTION ID url before routing to a new page. I am finding that Google is indexing these ACT urls and even promoting them above the actual page they link to.

How can I block search engines from indexing ACT urls?

Comment: I'd check-in with the AdMan folks on this. They should probably be explicitly setting a 301 (Moved Permanently) or 307 (Temporary Redirect) header before redirecting in order to prevent this from happening. If they simply use `$this->EE_>functions->redirect()`, then they're sending a 302 (Found) redirect, which could lead to this problem. (Search engines differ on whether they index the source or destination URLs in the case of 302 redirects.)

Comment: Agreed. I know it's a slightly different scenario, but I just checked bit.ly and they use 301 to redirect, which I believe forwards google juice to the destination URL. The only problem being that most browsers cache 301s, so if someone clicks the link twice it won't contribute to your analytics.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably write a .htaccess rule which 301s any URL with a certain ACT ID to a corresponding URL without. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457022/mod-rewrite-remove-query-string-from-url).